# add reference to linq for CodeDomProvider

Tags: c#, dynamic

I need to compile dynamic code in C#
but it has error :
" error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Linq' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)"

in pResults.Errors

my code is:

```
try {
    var className = "test1234";
    CodeNamespace ns = new CodeNamespace(className);
    CodeTypeDeclaration formulaClass =
    new CodeTypeDeclaration(className) {
        Attributes = MemberAttributes.Public
    };
    var constructor = new CodeConstructor { Attributes = MemberAttributes.Public };
    formulaClass.Members.Add(constructor);
    #region generate method
    var formula = @"List<string> UsedValues1 = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        UsedValues1.Add((i * i).ToString());
    }
    
    var ttt = UsedValues1.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Contains(""2""));
    return ttt;
    ";
    var method = new CodeMemberMethod {
        ReturnType = new CodeTypeReference(typeof(string)),
        Name = $"M{1}",
        Attributes = MemberAttributes.Public
    };
    method.Statements.Add(new CodeSnippetExpression($"{formula};"));
    #endregion
    formulaClass.Members.Add(method);
    ns.Types.Add(formulaClass);
    var pUnit = new CodeCompileUnit();
    pUnit.Namespaces.Add(ns);
    var pParams = new CompilerParameters {
        GenerateInMemory = true,
    };
    var provider = CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("csharp");
    var pResults = provider.CompileAssemblyFromDom(pParams, pUnit);
    var sw = new StringWriter();
    provider.CreateGenerator(sw).GenerateCodeFromNamespace(ns, sw, new CodeGeneratorOptions() {
    });
    var q = sw.ToString();
    if (pResults.Errors != null && pResults.Errors.Count > 0) {
        return;
    }
    var GeneratedClass =
    pResults.CompiledAssembly.CreateInstance($"{ns.Name}.{formulaClass.Name}");
    var methodParams = new List<double[]>();
    var ExecResult = (string)GeneratedClass.GetType().InvokeMember($"M{1}", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, GeneratedClass, methodParams.ToArray());
}
catch (Exception e) {
}
```

Comment: Looks like you should use a [CodeNamespaceImport](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.codedom.codenamespaceimport)

Comment: no . it has error : The type or namespace name 'Linq' does not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly reference?)} . 
when I use  this cod
       CodeNamespaceImport import1 = new CodeNamespaceImport("System.Collections.Generic");
                CodeNamespaceImport import3 = new CodeNamespaceImport("System.Linq");
                ns.Imports.Add(import1);
                ns.Imports.Add(import3);

Comment: help for god . my job is in danger . please...

Comment: Can you update your question with the new code?

Comment: try
    {
    var className = "test1234";
    CodeNamespace ns = new CodeNamespace(className );
    CodeNamespaceImport import1 = new CodeNamespaceImport("System"); 
    CodeNamespaceImport import3 = new CodeNamespaceImport("System.Linq"); 
    ns.Imports.Add(import1); 
    ns.Imports.Add(import3);
    CodeTypeDeclaration formulaClass =
    new CodeTypeDeclaration(className)
    {
    Attributes = MemberAttributes.Public
    };
    var constructor = new CodeConstructor { Attributes = MemberAttributes.Public };
    formulaClass.Members.Add(constructor);

Comment: I ran your code with the edit above, but the generated code didn't compile - `M1()` returns a bool, but `ttt` is a string, and there were brackets before the namespace declaration. If you can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64356960/edit) so it has working code, someone may be able to help you.